# C# Alternate ways to load a text file into a method?

Tags: c#, input

So I've been using the same code about a year now and normally I find new ways to do old tasks and slowly improve but I just seemed to of stagnated with this. I was curious if anyone could provide any insight on how I would do this task differently. I'm loading in a text file, reading all its lines into a string array and then looping those entries to perform a operation on each line.

```
string[] config = File.ReadAllLines("Config.txt");

foreach (string line in config)
{
    DoOperations(line);
}
```

Eventually I'll just be moving to openfiledialog, but that's for a time in the future and using OFG on a console application that's multi threaded seems like bad practice.

Comment: If your code works and you seek improvements or constructive criticism, you should ask instead on [codereview.se]

Comment: Thank you @Amy I wasn't aware of that site I'll note it down for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't act on the whole file at any point you could read it one line at a time. Given that your file looks like a config it's probably not a massive file, but if you were trying to read a large file in using File.ReadAllLines() you can get into memory issues. Reading one line at a time helps avoid that.

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("config.txt")){
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
        DoOperations(line);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You could rename `config` to `lines` for readability ;)
2. You could use `var`
3. `Select`? (if `DoSomething` returns something)

   ```
   var parsed = File.ReadAllLines("Config.txt").Select( l => Parsed(line));
   ```
4. `ForEeach`?

   ```
   lines.ToList().ForEach( l => DoSomething(line));
   ```
5. Read line by line with [ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8)?

   ```
   foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Config.txt"))
   {
    (...)
   }
   ```

   > The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.